# How to monitor Java Heap usage in Azure Monitor

Tags: java, azure, azure-monitor

How do I monitor the heap memory usage of my Java application with Azure Monitor and generate an alert when it's 90% used?

It seems that you can monitor the Heap of the JVM with Zabbix etc., but is it possible to do the same monitoring with Azure Monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure recommended way is to use [Azure Monitor Application Insights Java 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#autocollected-requests-dependencies-logs-and-metrics) which does not require any code change to your application. You can take a look at detailed configuration ( especially the JMX counter) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started?tabs=maven) which contains the heap memory.

```
<PerformanceCounters>
      <Jmx>
        <Add objectName="java.lang:type=ClassLoading" attribute="TotalLoadedClassCount" displayName="Loaded Class Count"/>
        <Add objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" attribute="HeapMemoryUsage.used" displayName="Heap Memory Usage-used" type="composite"/>
      </Jmx>
    </PerformanceCounters>
```

For adding alerts on these metrics you can consult the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log).